# Which one is faster to access frequently used data in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I need to use few variables frequently but I want know that which one will give fast response SQLite Database or Shared Preferences ?

Comment: Please explain in detail..!!!

Comment: If its few variables the you can use `SharedPreferences` but I would suggest use static variables instead

Comment: thanks @GirishNair ...but I tried with static variable, when my App stops and when I again starts App static variable is initialized with default value.

Comment: When your your app stops just save those variables in `SharedPreference` and when it starts again load it from `SharedPreferences` again

Answer (score 2):

**Shared Preferences:**

**What it is?**

Shared Preferences is an API from Android SDK to store and retrieve application preferences. Shared Preferences are simply sets of data values that stored persistently. Persistently which mean data you stored in the Shared Preferences are still exist even if you stop the application or turn off the device. SharedPreferences available at the Activity level or shared across all Activity in application package.

**When to use Shared Preferences?**

o   You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

o   Think of a situation where you want to save a small value (Login Credential) that would be referred later sometime when user launches the application. Then shared preference comes into action

**How to Use?**

```
SharedPreferences  sh_Pref = getSharedPreferences("Login Credentials", MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor toEdit = sh_Pref.edit(); 
toEdit.putString("Username", "Name");
toEdit.putString("Password", " Password"); 
toEdit.commit();
```

**SQLite Database:**

Android provides several ways to store user and app data. SQLite is one way of storing user data. SQLite is a very light weight database which comes with Android OS.

**How to use ?**

To use SQLite in Android, a java class should be created as a sub class of SQLiteOpenHelper. This class will act as a database controller which will have the methods to perform the CRUD operations. This custom java class should override the methods named onCreate() and onUpgrade().
onCreate() method will be called for the first time when the Android application is run. First the database instance should be created using the method like getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() based on the type of access required. Android supports this method by providing in-built methods. For that, SQLiteDatabase class should be used.